# 2sxc | Tinymce Table Cell Width

Tags: 2sxc

When I set a table to "width: 100%" using the Tinymce WYSIWYG it defaults to being the actual size of the table and not extend the table the entire width of a pane. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

My guess: you only set the field width to 100%, not the table. Check the html that's generated.